# Angular2 scope Issues

Tags: angular, typescript, scope

I'm having a weird issue regarding variables scoping and accessing the values in those variables.

I basically have this (short-sample) component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { InputText, DataTable, Button, Dialog, Column, Header, Footer, Panel, ProgressBar, Dropdown, SelectItem,
SplitButton, SplitButtonItem, Toolbar, SelectButton, OverlayPanel, Checkbox,
ToggleButton } from 'primeng/primeng';
import { User } from './../users.models';
import { UsersService } from './../users.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute }       from '@angular/router';
import { BbTile } from "./../../../shared/tile/tile.component";
import { BbTileModel } from "./../../../shared/tile/tile.model";

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/pages/users/dashboard/index.html',
    selector: 'brandbassador-app',
    // Honestly I'm not sure if all of these are required here
    directives: [(...), BbTile],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, UsersService]
})

export class UsersDashboardComponent {
    // Data variables
    tiles: BbTileModel[] = [];
    // Statistics variables
    totalRevenue: number;
    usersCount: number;
    averageEngagementRate: number;
    totalReach: number;

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("INIT    ");

        this.usersService.getUsers().then(
            users => {
                this.users = users;
                this.usersCount = this.users.length;
                this.getTotalRevenue();
                this.getAverageEngagementRate();
                this.getTotalReach();
                this.getMostActive();
                this.getTopPerformers();

                this.initTiles(); //The function to call
            });

        //Alternative call place
    }

    initTiles() {
        this.tiles.push(
            new BbTileModel("USERS", (this.usersCount).toString()),
            new BbTileModel("REVENUE", (this.totalRevenue).toString()),
            new BbTileModel("AVERAGE ENGAGMENT RATE", (this.averageEngagementRate).toString()),
            new BbTileModel("REACH", (this.totalReach).toString())
        );
    }
}
```

So, this is just a snippet of my component. And I'm having trouble accessing the local variables from within my InitTiles function.

Basically, whenever I have my function call on the current location (the one commented as `The function to call`) everything works ok.

However, if I move that call to outside of the `this.usersService.getUsers().then(...)` (The one commented as `Alternative call place`) I lose all ability of reading the values from the local component.

Why is this happening? Is it because the variables are being assigned inside the scope of the `getUsers` function or is there some other issue going on in the background regarding scopes?

Can anyone elaborate on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When

```
//Alternative call place
```

is executed, the call to `getUsers().then(...)` didn't happen yet.

This is normal behavior of async execution.
The code you pass to `then(...)` is executed when the response from the async call arrives. The code after `then(...)` is executed immediately.

Comment: Ok, so my error is that I'm expecting data to be there when it's not actually there yet. I figured it would be something of the likes. So I could say after the `then(...)` I could add another `then()` which would call/initialize the TileModel?

Comment: You can do that but what's the point of adding another `then(...)` when you can just move the code into the `then(...)` you already have.

Comment: No other reason than being kind of OCD :D